# Passing full bus with high impedance on some lines VS passing part of the bus

Tags: verilog

Do these codes are the same (in terms of functionality and number of gates) ?

```
module Test1(
    input enable,
    output [1:0] bus
);
    
    
    assign bus[1:0] = (enable) ? 2'b0 : 2'bZ;
    
endmodule
```

And this code :

```
module Test2(
    input enable,
    output [7:0] bus
);
    
    
    assign bus[1:0] = (enable) ? 2'b0 : 2'bZ;
    assign bus[7:2] = 6'bZ;
    
endmodule
```

If we call them like this :

```
module Test(
    input enable
);
    
    wire [7:0] bus;
    
    Test1 test1(.enable(enable), .bus(bus));
    // Or :
    Test2 test2(.enable(enable), .bus(bus));
    
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unconditionally assigning `'bZ` to a net is essentially a NOP. So the two modules are identical in functionalty.

Comment: There is one caveat: first `Test1 test1(enable, bus)` will not compile.  OP needs `bus[1:0]`. And in this case upper bits are initialized to z by Verilog convention.

Comment: Oh yes missed the port size mismatch. Some tools will just issue a warning.